# Ask about the HLT method of "Life cycle wage growth across countries"

Tags: mathematical-economics, labor-economics, stata

paper :https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/epdf/10.1086/696225

deaton imposes linear constraints in order to deal with the collinearity of age-period-cohort. How to implement it through stata?

Why  can the coefficients of $d_{t}^{*}=d_{t}-[(t-1)d_{2}-(t-2)d_{1}] $ sum to 0?

[image: The analysis of household surveys: A microeconometric approach to development policy (p126)]

Image Source:The analysis of household surveys: A microeconometric approach to development policy (p126)

Answer (score 3):

Let's take an example. Assume there are 5 periods, then the dummies take the following values:
$$
\begin{align*}
&d_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &0 &0 &0 &0 \end{bmatrix}\\
&d_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\\
&d_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
&d_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
&d_5 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
Now for $t = 3,\ldots, 5$ we define the vector:
$$
d^\ast_t = d_t + (t-2) d_1 - (t-1)d_2.
$$
This gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
d^\ast_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
d^\ast_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -3 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\\
d^\ast_5 = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -4 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
For every vector $d^\ast_t$ the coefficients sum to zero.

In general, the sum of the coefficients in $d^\ast_t$ will be equal to:
$$
-(t-1) + (t-2) + 1 = 0.
$$